# Is it possible to disable URL if it takes to the same page the user is on?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a navigation bar in my website with links to the important pages and I was wondering if there is a way using JS/PHP to disable the URL if it just goes to the same page the user is currently on to avoid too many redirections. For example (if the user is currently on the about page):

```
<a href="/index.php">Home</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a> //this url has been disabled because the user is currently on the about page
<a href="/contact.php">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work for you:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if (window.location.href == this.href)
        this.onclick = function() { return false };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with JavaScript you can use this

```
function redirectToNotCurrentUrl(event, this){
    if(window.location.href == $(this).attr('href')){
         event.preventdefault();
     }
}
```

then, call the function on click to a, for example

```
$("a").click(function(event){
   redirectToNotCurrentUrl(event, this);
});
```

or in one step

```
 $("a").click(function(event){
       if(window.location.href == $(this).attr('href')){
             event.preventdefault();
         }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<a href="<?=($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=={YOUR_PAGE_URL})?'javascript:void(0)':'{YOUR_PAGE_URL}'?>">About</a>
```